# File download in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html

I has a file with extension **.bpnm**, i need to download the file instead of displaying on the browser.Follwing is the code i used,

```
<a href="http://***FILE.bpmn" download>Download BPNM</a>
<a href="http://***FILE.pdf" download>Download PDF</a>
<a href="http://***FILE.xlsx" download>Download XLSX</a>
```

It is working fine with chrome for all the files, fairfox working fine with pdf and xlsx but facing problem with BPNM file. Incase of IE all formats are displaying content on the browser page itself and for the BPNM ,content is not actual, it is shwoing some xml content..

What would be the problem here?? Please help me

Comment: `download` is not supported in IE. To force download you need to add `content-disposition:attachment` headers.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add it!!

Comment: Its a server setting, do you have access to the server where the files are hosted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, you can add this to your .htaccess file in your web documents folder:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .bpmn
```

Comment: yes i'm using apache,but couldn't find .htaccess file, where it resides??

Comment: You won't have [a `.htaccess` file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) unless you create one. It's a place to put directory specific configuration information. You should avoid using them in favour of adjusting the main server configuration if you can.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin: , Raviteja: You can create the .htaccess file to your specific folder.

Comment: the .htaccess files may be hidden in unix/linus systems. you can find it by ls-a in command line. Or you can just use control + h in the gui mode.

Comment: thanks @Quentin and Sulthan: Is there any specific location to create this file or could i place it in conf folder?

Comment: You can create the .htaccess in your project file (In case of web server create in the www or public_html)

Comment: Still same problem :( I created in my project folder

Comment: Try it in chrome. You shall restart your apache and try that. Make sure the path of .bpnm file is correct.

Comment: In Chrome it is working fine, firefox is the problem for .bpnm

Comment: Is your firefox the latest one ?

Comment: Firefox 29.0 is the latest version. But i am not sure it is the actual problem for you.

Comment: You are seeing the output like xml output ?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [`download` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) . Note that it is not supported by all browsers.

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">
```

Comment: That would be the `download` attribute that you can see in the code in the original question? That the OP says doesn't work in IE? Which is the problem?

Comment: When click on Download BPMN file link, it has to download to the local,but it is not and content displaying in the browser is not actual content. This is the problem

Comment: @Quentin My point is that the documentation specifies it is not supported by the browser the OP mentions. So it's normal that it doesn't work.